# TextBox not same as PasswordBox at UI

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design

I am using [MaterialDesignInXAML](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)  from NuGet, my code is as follows:

```
 <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox    Background="Red" Grid.Column="0"  materialDesign:HintAssist.FloatingScale="1" materialDesign:HintAssist.FloatingOffset="0,-25" materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="User Name"/>
            <PasswordBox Background="Red" Grid.Column="1"  materialDesign:HintAssist.FloatingScale="1" materialDesign:HintAssist.FloatingOffset="0,-25" materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Password"/>
</Grid>
```

but in the view it looks different:
[image]

Same code for TextBox and PasswordBox, but different results, my question is how can make the TextBox and passwordbox to look the same, (I want to keep using the material design part)

Comment: use a style to make them both look the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say 'to look the same', are you saying your want the red background of the passwordbox to match the red background of the textbox? Or the other way around?

Either way, the problem is that the MaterialDesignInXaml library control templates for the TextBox and PasswordBox controls are slightly different. The element within those templates that bind to the Background property are not the same.

You could always modify their template for the PasswordBox to meet your needs:
https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.PasswordBox.xaml

Look at where the {TemplateBinding Background} is set, and take it from there.

If you strongly feel they should match in terms of styling, then why not raise an Issue on their GitHub site?